# Converter lista UL em radial

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando transformar um infográfico imagem em algo editável em HTML/JS/CSS.

Gostaria de deixar o mais próximo do da imagem. Preciso que seja flexível o suficiente para não precisar passar coordenadas via CSS de cada item, para que seja editável via admin (acrescentar/remover).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mais próximo que consegui, foi utilizando TweenMax através de um exemplo que peguei na internet. Mas, não consigo sair disso. Minha duvida maior é como posicionar o texto de acordo com a área onde está (se o círculo está a direita, alinhar o título a direita, se está a esquerda, fazer o mesmo alinhando à esquerda).

```js
function radiallist(trgt) {
    var itemAmount = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item').length;
    var angle = 0,
      currItem;
    var itemStartDist = trgt.width() * 2;
  for (i = 0; i < itemAmount; i++) {
   currItem = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
   angle = (Math.PI * 2 / itemAmount) * i;
   x = itemStartDist * Math.cos(angle) - (currItem.width() / 2);
   y = itemStartDist * Math.sin(angle) - (currItem.height() / 2);
   TweenMax.to(currItem, 0, {
    x: x,
    y: y
   });
  }
    radiallistItemPos($('.radiallist'));
 }
 radiallist($('.radiallist'));

 function radiallistItemPos(trgt) {
  var itemAmount = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item').length;
  var angle = 0,
  currItem;
  var itemEndDist = 100 * itemAmount/8;
  for (i = 0; i < itemAmount; i++) {
   currItem = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
   angle = (Math.PI * 2 / itemAmount) * i;
   x = itemEndDist * Math.cos(angle) - (currItem.width() / 2);
   y = itemEndDist * Math.sin(angle) - (currItem.height() / 2);
   TweenMax.to(currItem, 2, {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    alpha: 1
   });
  }
 }
```

```css
.radiallist {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
 .radiallist .radiallist-btn {
  position:relative;
  height:330px;
  width:330px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-165px;
  margin-left:-165px;
  z-index:2;
  text-align:center;
  border:3px dotted #CCC;
  border-radius:165px;
 }
 .radiallist .radiallist-btn img {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-107px;
  margin-top:-31px;
 }
 .radiallist .radiallist-items {
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
 }
 .radiallist .radiallist-item {
  position:absolute;
  background:url(https://i.imgur.com/LMgR3Pe.png) no-repeat center;
  z-index:1;
  text-align:right;
  font-family:'Din';
  font-size:14px;
  color:#777;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section id="conteudo">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="radiallist">
   <div class="radiallist-btn"></div>
   <ul class="radiallist-items">
    <li class="radiallist-item">Televisões</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Telas Touch</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Notebooks</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Tablets</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Impressoras</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Estruturas Box Truss</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Backdrops</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Palcos</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Caixas de som</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Microfones</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Iluminação</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Filmadoras</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas fotográficas</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Climatizadores</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Rádios</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Totens Carregadores</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Tendas</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Geradores de Energia</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Vídeo-games</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Equipamentos para transmissão</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Unifilas</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Pulpitos</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas de neve</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas de fumaça</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas de gelo seco</li>
    <li class="radiallist-item">Projetores</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz a respeito?